# Replace values based on length

Tags: r

Im working on a text dataframe

```
v1     v2      v3       v4
A      fox     and      2 
birds  are     running  very  
fast   during  the      dark   
night
```

I need to replace all fields which contain less than 4 characters with a blank field

So my output would be

```
v1     v2      v3       v4
        
birds          running  very  
fast   during           dark   
night
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sapply` you can count number of characters for all the columns and replace them with blank if they are less than 4.

```
df[sapply(df, nchar) < 4] <- ''

df
#     v1     v2      v3   v4
#1                          
#2 birds        running very
#3  fast during         dark
#4 night
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c("A", "birds", "fast", "night"), v2 = c("fox", 
"are", "during", ""), v3 = c("and", "running", "the", ""), v4 = c("2", 
"very", "dark", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(nchar(.) < 4 ~ '', TRUE ~ .)))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  v1      v2       v3        v4    
  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr> 
1 ""      ""       ""        ""    
2 "birds" ""       "running" "very"
3 "fast"  "during" ""        "dark"
4 "night"  NA       NA        NA
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  v1    v2     v3      v4   
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
1 A     fox    and     2    
2 birds are    running very 
3 fast  during the     dark 
4 night NA     NA      NA
```