# Replace R data.frame columns values based on value length

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

Suppose I have the following df in R:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1234, 56789, 159, 45950, 7844, 678, 17, 28794), B = c(657, 823, 465, 756, 328, 122, 490, 990))
```

I need to replace values in column A that have a length less than 4 with "", but I don't want to filter out those rows. Values with a length greater than 4 can remain as is. I've referenced the post [Replace values based on length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005466/replace-values-based-on-length) but have had no luck as the code doesn't perform any action on the column.

```
file['A'][sapply(file['A'], nchar) < 4] <- ""
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataframe has characters you could use `nchar` to count the number of character with `sapply` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = as.character(c(1234, 56789, 159, 45950, 7844, 678, 17, 28794)), B = as.character(c(657, 823, 465, 756, 328, 122, 490, 990)))
df[sapply(df, \(x) nchar(x) < 4)] <- ""
df
#>       A B
#> 1  1234  
#> 2 56789  
#> 3        
#> 4 45950  
#> 5  7844  
#> 6        
#> 7        
#> 8 28794
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

If your dataframe has numeric values, you could change all values less than 1000 like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(1234, 56789, 159, 45950, 7844, 678, 17, 28794), B = c(657, 823, 465, 756, 328, 122, 490, 990))
df[sapply(df, \(x) x < 1000)] <- ""
df
#>       A B
#> 1  1234  
#> 2 56789  
#> 3        
#> 4 45950  
#> 5  7844  
#> 6        
#> 7        
#> 8 28794
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! Follow up question as I'm new-ish to R, what is this section of the code doing: 

"\\(x)"

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @MKN17, Glad it helped you! The `\(x)` is the same as `function(x)` which was added to R 4.1.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to replace x for length less than 4 (assuming no float number), it might be df[df <= 999]="X"

```
      A B
1  1234 X
2 56789 X
3     X X
4 45950 X
5  7844 X
6     X X
7     X X
8 28794 X
```